# How to dinamicaly create multiple Table Classes in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, oop, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to create multiple classes in SQLAlchemy to generate specific tables.

I found different things here and more on [https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#**import**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#__import__) and https://python-course.eu/oop/dynamically-creating-classes-with-type.php

It seems clear enough, but their examples is using global opeartions, and I don't understand exactly how can I use as a sub function in something like this:

```
class _Table(Base):
    __tablename__ = '_table'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = Column(String)

table_list = ['Table1', 'Table2']

def table_class_generator(table_list):
    # here I need to create the tables

def tables_operators():
    # here I make operations on tables
```

So I need this one to convert globally to something like:

```
class Table1(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'table1'
    id = ...
    name = ...

class Table2(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'table2'
    id = ...
    name = ...

def table_operators():
    #
```

Comment: Found this a way to "reflect", it is an option to create a table by directly with SQL than use this to create tables? ... 
 https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/reflection.html#sqlalchemy.engine.reflection.Inspector.reflect_table

Comment: For ORM you can use [automap](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/extensions/automap.html)

Comment: I must confess that I'm new to SQLAlchemy and actually want to use in AWS Lambda. I just want a confirmation. Doing automap or reflection way in `def table_class_generator` I can use directly as <table_name> in `def table_operators` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Gord Thompson because he gave me another track.
I believe the solution will be this, I only test the init of database.

```
def tables_constructor(names: list) -> list:
    """
    Creates all tables in the database
    :return: 
    """
    engine = get_engine()
    metadata_obj = MetaData()
    table_names = []

    for name in names:
        name_obj = Table(
            name,
            metadata_obj,
            Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True),
            Column('timestamp', Integer)
        )
        table_names.append(name_obj)
    metadata_obj.create_all(engine)
    return table_names

def do_something()
    #

def start_app():
    names = ["Table_1", "Table_2"]
    tables = tables_constructor(symbols)
    do_something(tables)
```

Now I think I can do things in tables as they are mapped to table objects.

Would be cool to improve to define table columns somewhere else. I tried but isn't working.